# Difference between onclick="myFunction()" and document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment

What exactly is the difference between

`onclick="myFunction()"`

and

In normal JS - `document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click", myFunction);`

In React - `onClick={onClickFunction}>`

In the first one, we are calling the function. But in the second one, we are passing the function as a reference.

So when we pass the function reference, how does the function gets called when the click event happens?

Both works exactly as expected. But I would like to understand the underlying concept.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [addeventlistener-vs-onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick) ?

Comment: In React it is something special, see [React SyntheticEvent](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html).